# Consider $n$ random variables with the same pairwise correlation $\rho$. What is the range of $\rho$?

Tags: random-variables, correlation

Correlation coefficient can be interpreted as the cosine of the angle, $\theta$ between the centered random variables in a vector space. When $\cos \theta = \rho = 1$, we have $\theta = 0$.
When $\cos \theta = \rho = -1$, we have $\theta = \pi$.

Because all $n$ random variables have the same pairwise correlation, I believe the range of $\rho$ is limited to $1$ only. The angle between the random variables in vector space can only be $0$, otherwise we would contract the given constraint that all pairwise correlation coefficients are the same.

Is this the right idea?

Comment: Why can't you have $n$ orthogonal random variables? And hence all have pair-wise correlation $\rho = 0$.

Comment: Range of $\rho$ is $[-\frac1{n-1},1]$. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/72790/119261.

Comment: @Gregory You're right... hmmm my logic was off

Comment: @Gregory I think my mind was only thinkign about the 2D vector space. In that situation, I think their pairwise correlation have to be all 1.